# Excluding records from a DataSource on VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I trying to figure out a way of excluding records from a DataSource (As in DataSource component in Visual Studio) comming from a SQL Server 2005 database table.

Let say I have a Users table (`tblUsers`) which has a Boolean field (`isActive`) to determine if the user is Active or not. So I add my DataSource and can clearly see it (on runtime) displaying all my users, now lets say I want to show only those who are actually active. Pretty much like on SQL would be a simple `SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE isActive = 1`

I figured I could create a View excluding such users and use it as my DataSource but I thought of asking if there's a way of accomplishing the same on runtime, might come in handy for other tasks in the future.

Comment: So you want to return everything from the database and then filter the results rather than filter the query? This is a terrible idea.

Comment: What would be a better approach?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the entire table of users, or can you just select the ones into a dataset Where isActive = 1 ?

Comment: Any reason `ADO` objects with an SQL query would not work?

Comment: @HKImpact No, no particular reason other than inexperience. I just need my currently active users but I don't know how to exclude the rest from the dataset. I believe the easy fix would be create a View and work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like views, but to all their own. If you want to execute a SQL statement to filter some results, you can always populate a dataset like this.

```
 Dim oConn As New SqlConnection("<your connection string>")

 Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE isActive = 1"

 Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, oConn)
 Dim oDA As New SqlDataAdapter(oCmd)
 Dim oDS As New DataSet

 oDA.Fill(oDS)

 oConn.Dispose()
 oCmd.Dispose()
 oDA.Dispose()
 oDS.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I would have a go with this code.